# URL scheme reference for the Keynote iPad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, keynote

I'm trying to launch the Keynote app from the application that I'm building. How can I know the URL scheme supported by Keynote (if any) ?

Comment: See: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes  (does not contain Keynote, though). And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173749/how-to-open-keynote-app-from-another-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iTunes, sync apps, then go to apps in the navigation bar, Ctrl-click Keynote, show in Finder, copy it over to the desktop, change it's name to end with .zip, unzip it, open the payload folder, Ctrl-click Keynote.app, select Show Package Contents and view its Info.plist. :)

Comment: Dude there's is just one file in the Payload folder and its an Applicaton kind (so wont open). There aint no  info.plist here

Comment: Ctrl-click it and select Show package contents.

Comment: To save you some work -- as of version 1.7.2, there isn't a URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3

```
let keynoteUrl = URL(string: "x-keynote-live://")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(keynoteUrl! as URL)
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(keynoteUrl!)
}
```

In Objective-C

```
NSURL *keynoteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"x-keynote-live://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:keynoteUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:keynoteUrl];
}
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506556/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)